# Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError:

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

A very strange behavior is happening..

This works...

https://jsfiddle.net/ymgzrped/

But this below version does not...

https://jsfiddle.net/ymgzrped/1/

I changed...

```
 function fillInAddress()
```

to

```
 function fillInAddress(mapcomponents)
```

Used like this (working)

```js
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress)
```

and this (not working)

```js
autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress(new_mapcomponents))
```

For some reason, when I pass a parameter in, I get an error:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'place.address_components')
fillInAddress — _display:176
initAutocomplete — _display:162
(anonymous function) — js:145:280
(anonymous function) — js:145:119
promiseReactionJob
https://jsfiddle.net/js/makeStreamConfig.js.map
```

It seems to be some sort of scoping error with the code when I pass a parameter, but not when I do not.

What would cause this?

Thank you

Comment: The difference is `autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress)` passes `fillInAddress` as a function reference whereas `autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress(new_mapcomponents))` attempts to execute `fillInAddress` immediately

Comment: @phil solution: https://jsfiddle.net/bawqyd3n/. thank you

Comment: @Phil, In what example use case would you just pass the function, with no execution? Can you show an example?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the question

Comment: Why would someone just pass a function, without wrapping it in an anonymous function to execute it?

Comment: If you mean, why pass `functionReference` instead of `function() { functionReference() }`, the answer would be because they both do exactly the same thing only the former doesn't introduce any extra objects