# Stub is not executing callback (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, stub, stubbing

Here is a simplified version of my code. My callback is not getting called in my tests.

You can play with the code here to test it...

https://jsfiddle.net/ax3svk78/

`function(){ return fillIn(myArg);`

```
   function fillIn() {
    return true;
   }

   var stubAutoComplete = {
           addListener: function(event={}, callback={}) {
             callback;
           }
       }

   stubAutoComplete.addListener('place_changed',
                                             function(){ return fillIn(myArg); }
                                            );
```

I need the anonymous function, per this posting:
[Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296810/unhandled-promise-rejection-typeerror)

My non-stubbed code works, but my stub does not.

How do I modify my stubbed AddListner function to call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you really want but your code works with these changes:

- Define `myArg` variable
- Write `callback()` instead of `callback`

https://jsfiddle.net/va51Luqp/